# Woocommerce - Add multiple stores

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to create multiple stores in woo-commerce, where admin can make multiple users and user can open his own store and can sell his product.

I just want to know, is it possible in woo-commerce. If yes than please let me know how, and suggest how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Just have a template database and theme ready, when a new store is needed then deploy it (can be set up as a bash script).

Without heavy modding this is not possible, and honestly it would be a waste of time doing it that way around.

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce has a plugin for this now called 'Product Vendors': http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-vendors/

Hope this is what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not currently possible the way I think you want it.

The plugin named by @Adamj is not a complete solution for multi stores and network of eCommerces. Basically it just gives the possibility to earn commissions on products assigned to other users.

If you are looking for a more complete solution, have a look to **WooMU** http://woomu.org

It's an Open Source version of WooCommerce that is focusing on MultiSite and Multi Stores functionalities.

They are still in Alpha development. The Beta it's not released yet.

In the meantime you can join their community to share your ideas or to contribute in the development.

I am contributing :)

Comment: thanks for answer but the question is more than a year old

Comment: @Vicky Well...better than never :D